# Are there any commands starting with Z other than ZZ and ZQ?

Tags: normal-mode

As far as I understand it is the only two commands that exist.
And this "Z" chosen because it not used for anything else. But I am not sure.

Sorry for such basic question.
I tried to use `:help` but it looks case insensitive (as well as google).
Also `:help Z` leads to `-Z` flag which is not helpful in my case.

Comment: `:help index` has a list of all key bindings; it's not always 100% up-to-date, but should usually be fairly comprehensive. I only see `ZZ` and `ZQ` in there.

Comment: `:helpgrep \*Z` and `:helpgrep ^Z` also suggest `ZZ` and `ZQ` are the only default Z-bindings.

Comment: Good finding @Martin! I was checking the source code, which I guess is authoritative, but also included a reference to the index in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the docs, there's [`:help normal-index`](https://vimhelp.org/index.txt.html#normal-index) listing the Normal-mode keybindings, which only lists `ZZ` and `ZQ` starting with the `Z` prefix.

The Vim source code also confirms that, prefix `Z` is handled by the [`nv_Zet()` function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/normal.c#L3449), which only has cases for `Z` and `Q` following it.

So, yes, only `ZZ` and `ZQ`.